# What is the algorithm to come up with to find the areas of "islands"?

Tags: c

The program should find the areas of islands. **1** in the matrix indicates island, while **0** indicates water.

So I have a program to only scan and print the islands and water around them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int rows, columns;
    scanf("%d %d", &rows, &columns);

    if(rows>10 || columns>10) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        int islands[rows][columns];

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
                scanf("%d", &islands[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<columns; j++){
                printf("%d ", islands[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }


    }

}
```

Max. number of matrix that represent our islands is 10x10.

For example, if the user inputs next numbers:

```
3 3 //for rows and columns
1 0 1
1 0 0
0 0 0
```

As it's seen, the first island is 1s at the **matrix[0][0]** and **matrix[1][0]**, second island is at the **matrix[0][2]**.

Thus, the output would be `2 1` since those are the areas of islands.

I've been banging my head against the wall but still could not find the way to do that. What could be the possible way to solve the problem?

Comment: Search for *flood filling* algorithm, this is basic in computer graphics. Those algorithms are used to paint island, but painting or counting is almost the same : visit the whole space of an island.

Comment: It's similar to a floodfill. Follow and mark up connected "land".

Comment: If there was a 1 at [2][1] would that count as a separate island, or would it be part of the first island?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica it would be considered as a separate island.

Comment: Is it possible to have an island with a lake inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you must fill an island with the same character. You can do this using a recursive function. It simply look at the character on (x,y), if the character is an empty island, we fill it and look at the four adjacent corners.

```
void fill_island(char pattern, int x, int y, char **map, int size_x, int size_y) {
   if (map[x][y] == 1)
      map[x][y] = pattern; // fill the island
   else
      return; // if we are out of the island we stop this branch.
   if (x - 1 >= 0)
      fill_island(pattern, x - 1, y, map, size_x, size_y);
   if (x + 1 < size_x)
      fill_island(pattern, x + 1, y, map, size_x, size_y);
   if (y - 1 >= 0)
      fill_island(pattern, x, y - 1, map, size_x, size_y);
   if (y + 1 < size_y)
      fill_island(pattern, x, y + 1, map, size_x, size_y);
}
```

In your main function you have to loop over all the matrix and call the fill function

```
char pattern = 'a';
for (int x ; x < size_x ; x++)
   for (int y ; y < size_y ; y++) {
       if (map[x][y] == '1') {
          fill_island(pattern, x, y, map, size_x, size_y);
          pattern++;
       }
}
```

And then you just have to count each character to know the size of an island and sort the results to get your expected output.

Comment: Aside: Consider `(x  > 0)` versus `(x - 1 >= 0)`.  Easier to read and never overflows.